# irregular characters displayed when trying to select values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am executing a simple select query in mysql. When I view the values using phpMyAdmin, everything looks normal. But once I execute a select query in terminal.. Irregular characters like these show.

```
                                                                                                                   ��S8"�����g��n��Q�5��S:���p/��F;X�޳.�g����W�=��r+:��J�3W
\��S�R��CΤS�4�9�@�5���lˠ��bc�Q�}Q��(8>Vm���0�RU6L�FO#�W����W�SR>~�9$�-Q[XȲ�z�L�T�j  �~���@˔{���ZQUX�ǑZ:L&[�־[-�>z)5�A�ּd 9��H����^��w��xq&���kK��ʺs��R*-�3�Z����� ��#i ����;��C
```

�־������

Answer (score 1):

The phpMyAdmin interface can handle unicode - your terminal cannot

Comment: what may be the possible solution for this?

Comment: Either a) Get a terminal to be able to handle unicode or b) not have unicode in you database

Comment: Isn't it possible to do SET NAMES 'UTF8'

Comment: @thtsigma - I have not got a clue as to the datatype of that column or the query being issued.